# Python to HTML Function Call

Tags: python, html, function, flask

Im creating a program for school and i'm in this situation where im trying reduce code usage and was tring to make the HTMLsend function and just pass a single variable in and then it dose it. What can is do? and if not doable is there another alternative?

```
isLogin = False
snailtrail = ["home"]

def HTMLsend(pageset):
        global isLogin
        global snailtrail
        if isLogin == False: #deafult login page
            return render_template("Index.html", page=pageset, islogin = False, snailtrail=snailtrail)
        elif isLogin == True: #if someone is logged in show a different page
            return render_template("Index.html", page=pageset, islogin = True, snailtrail=snailtrail, accessLevel=session["accessLevel"])

@app.route("/login")
    def login():
        pageset="login"
        global snailtrail
        SnailChecker(snailtrail, pageset)
        HTMLsend(pageset)
```

And It spit out the error:
"TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement."
Can i get around this?

Thanks :D

Comment: The route expects a return value. The solution to work around the error is to pass the returned HTMLSend result on. `return HTMLsend(pages)`
Your approach to minimize the code seems very creative to me but unfortunately not really useful.  
Please avoid global variables as long as possible. Why don't you use the session memory more often?